# Convert audio file real time to text

Tags: c#

I am looking to convert a audio from PC in real time to text using C#; namely the System.Speech namespace. My code is mentioned below;

The is working perfectly with sample .wav  file. But how can i do this in real time

```
recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(Server.MapPath("~/spoken.wav"));
recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();
label1.Text = result.Text;
```

I expect when i start on my PC some .wav file the program must recognize it.

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtodefaultaudiodevice?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: I think you want to use a memory steam so you do not have to save to a file.

Comment: @jdweng Yes just convert .wav to text

Comment: You need to read the microphone input that creates a wav into a string instead of saving to a .wav file.  See : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19485/A-Voice-Chat-Application-in-C

Comment: @jdweng No I need to read PC output

Comment: When I start my audio file the program must convert audio to string

Comment: The chat program will show you how to get the voice real time.  You just need to send the results to the Speech application instead of sending over TCP.